# Element is already the child of another element when doesnt exist?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I'm trying to programatically create a button flyout, within my XAML I have:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="LaunchFlyout" Content="LAUNCH">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout Placement="Top">
                <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" />
                        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</Page.Resources>
```

Nested within `grids` I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="launchBtn_grid" Grid.Column="1">
</Grid>
```

And then in my code within the `Page_Loaded` method I have:

```
bool hasContainer = localSettings.Containers.ContainsKey("appStatus");

if (!hasContainer) {
    Button button = (Button)this.Resources["LaunchFlyout"];
    launchBtn_grid.Children.Add(button);
}
else {
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Content = "LAUNCH";
    button.Click += launch_btn_Click;
    launchBtn_grid.Children.Add(button);
}
```

When I debug this, it reaches the IF statement and reaches this line `launchBtn_grid.Children.Add(button);` and then I get this error **Element is already the child of another element.**

Does anyone understand why? I have already looked and they dont already exist so I don't understand why it is giving me this error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is `button.Parent` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt It says its null?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what context/use case your are doing that, but it feels weird to me to have an actual control as a `Resource` (not a `DataTemplate`, `Style`, etc).

If you only want to have 1 button of the 2 different template, why not switch `Visibility` on the 2 instead of loading controls from your code behind ?

Going forward with the idea, just add both buttons in the `Grid` within your XAML and switch their `Visibility` according to the setting you read.

There is a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) within the framework to help you with this.